# Eclipse github plugin: Committing changes error - Entry not found by path

Tags: android, github, eclipse-plugin

I am facing a weird github behaviour.

I am using the github plugin for eclipse (3.7.2), and now if I create a new class and try to commit, I get an error like

```
An internal error occurred
Entry not found by path: /omeFolderName/src/com/...
```

Originally, the file is located in `/SomeFolderName/src/com/...`, but somehow github ignores the first letter of the folder name. Any idea how to fix that? This wasn't a problem the last days..

- on my hard drive, the file is located in the right folder `/SomeFolderName/src/com/...`
- I tried clean/close the project, restart eclipse, but without any effect
- also if I copy paste an existing class, the new one is missing the first letter as well

Comment: we solved this by deleting the whole repositry and re-pushed everything. we couldn't really find the reason why this was happening... any explainations welcome!

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem too. I don't know why the first letter was missing, it may have been a second glitch. The real problem was solved by clicking the "Add to Git Index" button. Once I did the Add to Index, my Commit worked fine. No idea why the first letter was missing on the error.

Comment: I added a git ignore to a folder link (containing resources) to a separate project in eclipse. Once I did that, issue disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

This really worked to me!

1) Copy your project to somewhere else;

2) Delete your damaged project from eclipse;

3) Create a new project with the same name;

4) Add this project to your branch;

5) Copy from your original project, the src, test, build.xml or whatever specific files you need, do not copy project related files;

6) synchronized and commit again.

Thats it!

Answer (score 0):

Just for future help. I had the same problem and i used the desktop github tool.
http://mac.github.com/ or http://windows.github.com/
i used the tool to make the commit from there. I closed eclipse just for be sure i did the commit with tool and i reopened eclipse. The commit was done successfully. I think this is a plugin's bug. Also noticed that this occurs when you copy-paste new files into project and not happening when drag and drop them.

Comment: you could edit your answer again and add the comment :-) Thanks.